# Maven - No source to compile warning

Tags: java, maven, testng, pom.xml

Im having some trouble running the TestNG Suite from my Maven project.

At the moment i have my two suites defined in my pom file but when i run my pom file as a Maven test im getting the following warnings in the console saying there is no code to compile. Any help on how to resolve this problem would be appreciated

[image: Console output]

[image: Project Hierarchy]

[image: POM.xml file]

Comment: Could you modify your question and add the console output and pom as text instead of pictures?

Comment: the maven standard is to have "src/main/java" directories. in your case ,there is only "src"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your directory structure appears to not be the expected standard directory structure layout.

You do not have a `src/test/java/` directory with any source in it!

Your actual source code should be in `src/main/java` as well. You should not be specifying it in a non-standard location.

You should always create your Maven projects with `mvn archetype:generate` so that they are correctly laid out.